# Jupiters decreasing radius, inconsistency between two results

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I will go through 2 slightly different calculations of the problem below.

> Jupiter emits roughly twice as much energy into space as it receives from the Sun. The difference is
>   thought to be produced by continuing slow gravitational contraction of the planet. Assuming that the
>   gravitational potential energy of the planet ' $GM^2/R$ (where the missing constant of proportionality
>   is of order unity) estimate by how much the radius of the planet must change each year.

$$R_{\text{Jup}}=7 \times 10^7\,\mathrm{m}$$

$$d_{\text{Sun-Jup}}=5.2 \,\mathrm{AU}=5.2 \times 1.5 \times 10^{11}\,\mathrm{m}$$

$$L_{\text{Sun}}=4 \times 10^{26}\,\mathrm{W}$$

$$M_{\text{Jup}}=1.9 \times 10^{27}\,\mathrm{kg}$$

The Suns power, $L_{\text{Sun}}$ is spread over a sphere of radius $d_{\text{Sun-Jup}}$ given by $$F_{\text{Sun}}=\frac{L_{\text{Sun}}}{4\pi \,{d_{\text{Sun-Jup}}}^2}$$
where $F_{\text{Sun}}$ is the flux emitted by the sun. But Jupiter only intercepts $\pi R_{\text{Jup}}^2$ (a disk) of this flux, so the intercepted power (or luminosity received from the Sun) is

$$\pi R_{\text{Jup}}^2\frac{L_{Sun}}{4\pi \,{d_{\text{Sun-Jup}}}^2}=\frac{1}{4}L_{\text{Sun}}\left(\frac{R_{\text{Jup}}}{d_{\text{Sun-Jup}}}\right)^2=\frac{4\times 10^{26}}{4}\times\left(\frac{7\times 10^7}{5.2\times 1.5\times 10^{11}}\right)^2\approx 8\times 10^{17}\,\mathrm{W}$$

The excess power $P$ released through gravitational contraction is

$$P=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{GM^2}{R}=GM^2\frac{d}{dR}\frac{1}{R}\frac{dR}{dt}=-\frac{GM^2}{R^2}\frac{dR}{dt}$$
I wish to solve the differential equation
$$P=-\frac{GM^2}{R^2}\frac{dR}{dt}\tag{1}$$

Applying boundary conditions such that $$t=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{when}\,\,\, R=7\times 10^7\,\mathrm{m}\,\,\, \text{(Jupiters initial radius)} \\ 3.1\times 10^7, &\text{when}\,\,\, R= \text{Jupiter radius after 1 year}\,\,(3.1\times 10^7\,\mathrm{s})\end{cases}$$

Separating variables and integrating $(1)$

$$\int_{R'=R_{Jup}}^{R}\frac{1}{{R'}^2}dR'=-\frac{P}{GM^2}\int_{t=0}^{1\,\mathrm{Yr}}dt$$

$$\implies-\bigg[\frac{1}{R'}\bigg]_{7\times 10^7}^{R}=-\frac{P}{GM^2}\bigg[t\bigg]_{0}^{3.1 \times 10^7}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{7\times 10^7}=\frac{8\times 10^{17}\times 3.1\times 10^7}{6.7\times 10^{-11}\times\left(1.9\times 10^{27}\right)^2}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{R}=\frac{8\times 10^{17}\times 3.1\times 10^7}{6.7\times 10^{-11}\times\left(1.9\times 10^{27}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{7\times 10^7}=\frac{7\times 10^7\times 8\times 10^{17}\times 3.1\times 10^7+6.7\times 10^{-11}\times\left(1.9\times 10^{27}\right)^2}{7\times 10^7\times 6.7\times 10^{-11}\times\left(1.9\times 10^{27}\right)^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{R}=\frac{56\times 3.1\times 10^{31}+6.7\times 3.61\times 10^{43}}{7\times 6.7\times 3.61\times 10^{50}}=\frac{173.6+24.187\times 10^{12}}{169.309\times 10^{19}}$$

$$\implies R=\frac{169.309\times 10^{19}}{173.6+24.187\times 10^{12}}$$

Using Wolfram Alpha to evaluate this

[image: Wolfram Alpha result 1]

this corresponds to a radius decrease (per year) of

[image: Wolfram Alpha result 2]

$0.0005024186546455856502068684140705373813750095\,\mathrm{m}$

---

There is another way to solve this problem, and that is by considering the fractional change in $R$

Let $\dot R =\frac{dR}{dt}$ and rearrange $(1)$ such that

$$\frac{\dot{R}}{R}=-P\frac{R}{GM^2}$$

Inserting the same values as before to *exactly* the same precision

$$\frac{\dot{R}}{R}=-8\times 10^{17}\times\frac{7\times 10^7}{6.7\times 10^{-11}\times \left(1.9\times 10^{27} \right)^2}=-\frac{56\times 10^{24}}{6.7\times 3.61\times 10^{43}}$$
$$\implies \frac{\dot R}{R}=-\frac{56}{24.187\times 10^{19}}\tag{2}$$
$$\implies \frac{\dot R}{R}=-\frac{56}{24.187\times 10^{19}}\approx -2.3 \times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$$

With $3.1 \times 10^{7}\,\mathrm{s}$ per year, the expected fractional contraction per year is about $7 \times 10^{−12}$.

Now, finally, to get the actual radius this corresponds to I multiply the RHS of $(2)$ by the number of seconds in a year and the initial radius of Jupiter

$$\implies R=\frac{56}{24.187\times 10^{19}}\times 7\times 10^7 \times 3.1\times 10^7$$

On simplification this gives

$$R=\frac{1215.2\times 10^{14}}{24.187\times 10^{19}}=\frac{1215.2}{24.187\times 10^5}$$

Evaluating this with Wolfram Alpha again:

[image: Wolfram Alpha result 3]

So the radius decrease this time is $0.0005024186546491917145574068714598751395377682\,\mathrm{m}$

---

Close inspection shows that these two numbers (to $46$ decimal places) are not identical:

$R=0.000\color{blue}{50241865464}55856502068684140705373813750095\,\mathrm{m}$ for the first method

$R=0.000\color{blue}{50241865464}91917145574068714598751395377682\,\mathrm{m}$ for the second method

I used the same precision throughout and only computed with Wolfram Alpha at the end, so why are these numbers *not* **exactly** equal?

Or, put in another way,

Why is

$$\frac{169.309\times 10^{19}}{173.6+24.187\times 10^{12}}\ne\frac{1215.2}{24.187\times 10^5}?$$

*Remark: I'm sorry for asking such a strange question. I just can't figure out why they are not equal and it's driving me mad. I also apologize for including many steps in the calculations, but I wanted to show each step to hopefully account for any possible errors.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you solve a differential equation
$$
\dot R = -cR^2\implies \frac1{R(t_0+\Delta t)}-\frac1{R(t_0)}=cΔt
\\
\frac{R(t_0+\Delta t)-R(t_0)}{R(t_0)}=-\frac{cR(t_0)Δt}{1+cR(t_0)Δt}
=-cR(t_0)Δt+(cR(t_0)Δt)^2-(cR(t_0)Δt)^3\pm\dots
$$
In the second case you use the derivative value at $t_0$ to compute the approximation $R_1\approx R(t_1)$ at $t_1=t_0+Δt$, which in effect is an Euler step
$$
R_1= R_0+\dot R(t_0)Δt\implies\frac{R_1-R_0}{R_0}= -cR_0Δt
$$
This is in first order the same, but misses the higher order terms. As you computed, $cR_0Δt\approx 7\cdot 10^{-12}$, so that the first 11 non-zero digits of both results should be the same, differences are to be expected at least in the 13th digit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the only part I don't understand is the implication in $R_1= R_0+\dot R(t_0)\Delta t\implies\frac{R_1-R_0}{R_0}= -cR_0 \Delta t$, if you subtract $R_0$ from both sides and then divide by $R_0$ then $\frac{R_1-R_0}{R_0}= \frac{\dot R(t_0)}{R_0}\Delta t$

Comment: The differential equation is the same as in the first case, $\dot R=-cR^2$.